# Creating an express project first run gives errors

Tags: node.js, express

I installed express globally.

I have created a new project called helloExpress like this:

```
express helloExpress -c less
```

Installed all dependencies:

```
cd helloExpress
sudo npm install
```

Run the app:

```
node app.js
```

Output error:

```
/home/dev/projects/helloExpress/app.js:1
s., */,,var expr
      ^

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Looking into the code of app.js it looks like this:

```
/**, * Module dependencies., */,,var express = require('express'),  , routes = require('./routes'),  , user = require('./routes/user'),  , http = require('http'),  , path = require('path');,,var app = express();// all environments,app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);,app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');,app.set('view engine', 'jade');,app.use(express.favicon());,app.use(express.logger('dev'));,app.use(express.bodyParser());,app.use(express.methodOverride());,app.use(app.router);undefined  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));,app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));,,// development only,if ('development' == app.get('env')) {,  app.use(express.errorHandler());,},,app.get('/', routes.index);,app.get('/users', user.list);,,http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){,  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));,});,
```

As you can see there are , everywhere. 
Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `node --version` and `express --version`? Express' CLI [uses `os.EOL`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.1/bin/express#L31-L33) when generating files, which was added with [Node 0.8](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/api/os.html#os_os_eol).

Comment: I think this could be the problem. I am using node version 0.6.12. I guess I should build it myself instead of using apt-get. I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonathan Lonowski said in the comments, the Node.js version I used was too old.

I installed a newer version of Node.js by following this tutorial: http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/